# Как сохранить изображение из файла docx с помощью python

Tags: python-3.x

Возникла необходимость пропарсить большое количество фалов формата docx и вытащить из них изображения. подскажите пожалуйста каким образом я могу это сделать.
связано ли положение изображения в документе с возможностью его извлечь?
Если есть возможность добавить их в файл Excel, тоже буду рад узнать способ.

Comment: воспользуйся `unzip`

Comment: @eri, Отлично! Спасибо большое!